# Why Can't I click this button? (Input type submit)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, triggers, submit

I have this Input type submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="step2" id="step2" class="btn_orange" value="Continue ››">
```

If I do a console.log of this button .val(), I get it:

```
console.log($("input#step2").val());

Result: "Continuar ››"
```

I put the following trigger to click the button:

```
if($price < 1){
    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">

            $(\"input#step2\").trigger(\"click\"); 

        </script>"; // TODO
} ?>
```

And doesnt works. If I write this code in the inspect, it works.

Where is the problem?

Regards

Comment: You're probable missing a document.ready handler

Comment: you have use a form tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(\"input#step2\").trigger(\"click\"); 
});
```

Makes sure the document is ready.

Comment: I used the same code in other script and It works, Why?

Comment: Hey, Your code works but I dont want to show the page. I have to jump it. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to be way more specific

Comment: I want to jump the page if $price < 1, I cant wait while the page is ready.